# SwiftUI - drawingGroup() changing colors

Tags: swiftui, drawing, metal

Why are my colors changing/inverting when I apply the .drawingGroup() modifier to improve performance?

It almost seems like they are inverting.  Going from Red to Black

I am not getting any error messages and code works as intended if I // (don't know the term, Hashing??) out the .drawingGroup() see screenshots at the end if unclear.

```
struct ColorCyclingCircle: View {
    var amount = 0.0
    var steps = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<steps) { value in
                Circle()
                    .inset(by: CGFloat(value))
                    .strokeBorder(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                        self.color(for: value, brightness: 1),
                        self.color(for: value, brightness: 0.5)
                    ]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom), lineWidth: 2)
            }
        
        }
        .drawingGroup()
    }
    
    func color(for value: Int, brightness: Double) -> Color {
        var targetHue = Double(value) / Double(self.steps) + self.amount
        
        if targetHue > 1 {
            targetHue -= 1
        }
        
        return Color(hue: targetHue, saturation: 1, brightness: brightness)
        
    }
}
```

[image: .drawingGroup()]

[image: // .drawingGroup()]

Comment: // is referred to a commenting out

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 (ie. no visual difference between w/ & w/o .drawingGroup)

Comment: Confirm presence on Xcode 11.4. It looks like was a bug.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 11.5 so present here too, good to hear its fixed in 12.0